# confused about how to access TreeDataProvider

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to write a extension for vscode but I am struggling to properly understand how to extend the TreeDataProvider. In the [example provided](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/fc9663af5c92dfb9abcaa93384d2b35893d9f4c6/tree-view-sample/src/nodeDependencies.ts)

```
export class DepNodeProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<Dependency> {
```

is possible. But the implementation in typescript is

```
export interface TreeDataProvider<T>
```

from my understanding typescript interfaces aren't exportable to standard javascript. How would I implement the TreeDataProvider if I am writing a extension in vanilla JS?

Comment: just leave out the generics part `export class DepNodeProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider { ...`

Comment: whoops, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that TypeScript has a structural type system.

You can think of it as static duck typing.

The use of the `implements` keyword on a class definition is completely optional. It doesn't actually have any impact at either compile time or runtime. Its only use is to provide an extra bit of correctness checking documentation, but it isn't ever required in TypeScript so it certainly isn't required in JavaScript.

So to answer the question directly, in vanilla JS just write

```
export class DepNodeProvider {
  // definitions of all members the interface requires.
}
```

Comment: How would I extend `vscode.TreeDataProvider` though, if it doesn't exist in vanilla js? I would just write my own TreeDataProvider and make sure my api matches the one that is shown in the docs?

Comment: @MikeF precisely. `vscode.TreeDataProvider` cannot exist in vanilla JavaScript because is a only a type. Why not write in TypeScript though?

Comment: No specific reason. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Javascript are just wrappers around functions.

Here is a most basic TreeDataProvider, written as a function:

```js
export default function MyAwesomeProvider(): vscode.TreeDataProvider<{}> {
  // do some stuff if you wish

  return {
    getTreeItem,
    getChildren,
    onDidChangeTreeData,
  }
}
```

According to the interface, only `getTreeItem` and `getChildren` are required in the object you return.

Here is an example of those functions:

```js
async function getChildren(element?: MyCustomType): Promise<MyCustomType[]> {
  const children = element
    ? await getSubListOfElement(element)
    : await getParentList()
  
  return children  
}

function getTreeItem(item: MyCustomType): vscode.TreeItem {

  return {
    id: `${item.id}`,
    collapsibleState: void 0,
    label: `${item.name}`,
    tooltip: `${item.description}`,
    iconPath: vscode.Uri.parse(item.avatarUrl),
  }
}
```

So, I don't know about you, but extending that seems a lot easier to me than faffing around with pseudo classes and this OOP stuff.

For example, you can create a higher-order function to wrap around `MyAwesomeProvider`, or you just do something else anywhere in those functions and get on with it.
Note, you could also just add more properties to the object your provider returns, but Typescript will complain that it doesn't match the interface anymore.

There's something to be said for ignoring types and just doing it the good old JS way (though never less than ES6, we're not savages after all).